# How can I strip all HTML codes except <sub> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, security

I need to remove all HTML tags except:

- it is `<sub>` tag
- there is {1 (or more) newline(s) + 4 (or more) spaces} in the behind of it
- it is surrounded into "`" character.

#### Here is an examples:

```
var str = "something1
           <sub>
             something2
             <div class='myclass'>something3</div>
           </sub>
           <div class='myclass'>something4</div>
           something5

               <div class='myclass'>something6</div>
           <div class='myclass'>something7</div>
           `<div>something8</div>`
           something9";
```

**Expected output:**

```
/*   
something1
<sub>
  something2
  something3
</sub>
something4
something5

    <div class='myclass'>something6</div>
`<div>something8</div>`
something9
```

---

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/wF2iI7/1) is what I've tried so far:

```
/\n\s{0,3}<.*[^>]+|<sub>.*?<\/sub>|`.*?`/gm
```

Comment: before using regex on HTML, read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5053002

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, agreed .. A HTML parser usually would be much better than regex for working on HTML. But I guess in this case regex is better.

Comment: Your `str` variable assignment isn't valid JS - is it just formatted like that to make it easier for us to read?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes exactly .. actually that's the value of a textarea.

Comment: Are you using JS in the backend? If yes I know npm validator can strip all HTML tags. I am not sure if you can allow certain tags. But if not, you can definitely create a new module and add your own method (pre-processing). 

I heard of npm striptags and npm string. They may allow certain tags. Read their doc.

Comment: @user3207158 ok, just as a note, I guess JS is front-end *(not back-end)* .. and yes I use it. thank you anyway.

Comment: @MartinAJ Not always..you can write JS code with nodejs in the backend

Comment: I don't think there's a *one regex to solve it all* here. You will probably have to split the thing by \n and then run each line, finding sub and what not.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with regex substitutions. Use this regex with `mg` modifiers:

```
(\n\n    .*|`[^`]+`|<\/?sub\b[^>]+>)|<[^>]+>
```

And use `$1` as the substitution.

There are several parts to this. The capturing group finds all the HTML you may want to keep:

- `\n\n    .*` An empty line, and another line that starts with 4 spaces.
- `` `[^`]+` `` Things in `` Back`Ticks ``.
- `<\/?sub\b[^>]+>)` This matches `sub` HTML elements, opening or closing.

The remaining HTML elements will match `<[^>]+>`, which is discarded.